# Smooth color transition with LESS

Tags: css, less

I'm using LESS to style a web page (with Bootstrap). What I'd like to do is add a smooth color transition when I hover my mouse over an element. Doesn't this functionality come right out of the box in LESS?

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
.list-group {
    .list-group-item:hover {
        background: fadein(@cn-sidemenu-hover-bg, 100%);
    }
    .list-group-item {
        background: @cn-sidemenu-bg;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

But this has no color animation. But the name kinda implies to me that this should do some sort of color animation?

Otherwise I don't see any difference between `fadein` and `lighten`..

How can I do a smooth color transition with LESS?

Comment: [The docs](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-fadein) cannot harm usually.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add a `transition` attribute to the .list-group-item class like:

```
.list-group-item{
background: @cn-sidemenu-bg;
color: #fff;
transition: background 500ms;
}
```

Transition tells the browser to interpolate between two defined attributes. fadein and lighten are LESS specific functions, that only process the color value resulting in a fixed color value. 
i.e. this
`lighten(#aa0000, 5)` would result in the color value #c30000;

fadein does the same thing of color manipulation, but edits the opacity value.